# MySQL find all persons who have not had an appointment in six months or more

Tags: mysql

Hi all I have an appointments table that has among other fields a DATE field that records the date of the appointment. The show create statement is below.

```
 | groomappointments | CREATE TABLE `groomappointments` (
   `gapmtDate` date NOT NULL,
   `gapmtClient` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `gapmtUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `gapmtStatus` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `gapmtSTime` time NOT NULL,
   `gapmtETime` time NOT NULL,
   `gapmtPet` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `gapmtService` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `gapmtTracker` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`gapmtDate`,`gapmtClient`,`gapmtUser`,`gapmtStatus`,`gapmtSTime`),
   KEY `gappPet` (`gapmtPet`),
   KEY `gappClient` (`gapmtClient`),
   KEY `gappSrve` (`gapmtService`),
   KEY `gappStat` (`gapmtStatus`),
   KEY `gappUsr` (`gapmtUser`),
   KEY `gapmtTracker` (`gapmtTracker`),
   CONSTRAINT `gappClient` FOREIGN KEY (`gapmtClient`) REFERENCES `clients` (`clientid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `gappPet` FOREIGN KEY (`gapmtPet`) REFERENCES `pets` (`petID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `gappSrve` FOREIGN KEY (`gapmtService`) REFERENCES `groomservices` (`groomServicesID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `gappStat` FOREIGN KEY (`gapmtStatus`) REFERENCES `aptstatus` (`aptStatusID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `gappUsr` FOREIGN KEY (`gapmtUser`) REFERENCES `users` (`userID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

I'm trying to query the database to find all clients whose last appointment was recorded six months or more in the past, but I can not figure out the correct query.

I've tried the following query which will give me all records that are recorded 6Mts+ in the past but includes clients who have had appointments in the last week, month etc.

```
 mysql> select groomappointments.gapmtDate, clients.firstname, clients.lastname
-> from groomappointments,clients
-> WHERE date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)>gapmtDate
-> AND clients.clientid = groomappointments.gapmtClient;
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select clients.firstname, clients.lastname, groomappointments.gapmtDate
from clients join groomappointments on clients.clientid = groomappointments.gapmtClient
where clients.clientid in (
  select gapmtClient from groomappointments
  group by gapmtClient
  where date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) > gapmtDate
)
```

Comment: Thanks your your reply but this query also gives me clients who have an appointment in the last week.

Comment: try ` ... group by gapmtClient having min(date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) > gapmtDate`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the max appointment date, and then see if thats > 6 months ago, or not at all. Such as

```
select appt.lastDate, clients.firstname, clients.lastname
from (select max(gapmtDate) as lastDate,gapmtClient from groomappointments group by gamptClient) as appt ,clients 
where date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)>lastDate
AND clients.clientid = appt.gapmtClient;
```

Untested, but, should work. or at least give you the starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'll have a look at this.

Comment: :) Sorry for the typo, Im dyslexic, so Im great at typos